# C program crashes on printing array

Tags: c, arrays, printf

I am learning C at the moment, and am trying to build a simple interpreter. It takes one character and one number. The program below only uses `'r'` for the char. The `'r'` stands for the range (of the natural numbers) and the digit after it specifies the length of the range.

Example Execution:

```
Enter:
      r 9
 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

What happens instead:

```
Enter:
      r 9
```

And here the program crashes. So I believe the error lies in the printing of the array.

The code in question is here:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int* range(int i) {
    int *a=(int*) malloc(i * sizeof(int));
    int j;
    for(j=0;j<i;j++)
        a[j]=j;
    return a;
}
void printArray(int a[], int length) {

    int i;
    printf("\n");
    for(i=0;i<length;i++)
        printf("%d  ", a[i]);

}

int main() {
    char c;
    int n = 1;
    while(n>=0){
        printf("\nEnter:\n\t");
        scanf("%c %d", c, n);
        if(c='r')
            printArray(range(n), n);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

So what is causing the program to crash?

Comment: `if(c='r')` you meant `if(c=='r')`

Comment: Notice that how you are handling the result of `range()` causes a leak. You need to hold this result in a variable. When you have finished your `printArray` method, `free` the memory you allocated with `malloc` (in this case, the result of `range()`).

Comment: And besides, don't forget to release this memory with `free`

Comment: Your first reaction as a programmer when you get a crash, should be to run your program in a debugger. It will show you where the crash happened, tell you the function call stack so you can see how you ended up there, and let you examine variables to help you understand what might have caused the crash.

Comment: You should also check the return code from `scanf`.

Comment: @Anonymous Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. Could you elaborate?

Comment: @RageD How do I free the memory of malloc? Is in the function itself or in the main?

Comment: You should free the memory when you are no longer using it (so, in this case, the `main()` method). You should try something like this: `int* r = range(n); printArray(r, n); free(r);` The `free()` method on a pointer allocated with `malloc()` will free the memory back to the operating system for future use. Here is a reference: http://linux.die.net/man/3/free

Comment: @Zchpyvr `scanf` returns an integer, either the number of items converted or an error code. You should read the definition of the function, and check that it returns (in this case) 2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your arguments to scanf are wrong, you need

```
scanf("%c %d",&c, &n);
```

Your fundamental problem here is that you have no evidence about where the crash is happening, as it happens I bet it's in scanf().

I recommend you adopt two debugging techniques:

a). Add print statements in your code so you know what's happening
b). Use an interactive debugger so you can step through and see what's going on.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I'll practice those techniques in the future.